# How to buffer a response in web app in golang?

Tags: go

I want to make a hello world web app that will properly catch template error. So I need to buffer the response but don't know how to do it. I've put together this code. Is this the way to buffer a response in golang?

```
func get_handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(buf, "hello.html", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    w.Write([]byte(buf.String()))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bytes.Buffer` has a [`Bytes`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Bytes) method, so you don't actually need to call `String` and convert it to `[]byte`:

```
w.Write(buf.Bytes())
```

Additionally, it's a good practice to write errors to stderr. Just replace your `fmt` with `log`:

```
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`bytes.Buffer` has a built-in method for writing out to an `io.Writer`:

```
func get_handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    //fill buffer

    _,err := buf.WriteTo(w)
    if err != nil { 
         log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

docs:  http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteTo

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `bytes.Buffer` "as is" by writing into it, but at the cost of discarding the buffer on every request.

Using a pooled approach (that safely resets the contents between use, but retains the buffer) can have some gains:

```
var bufPool *bpool.BufferPool

func YourHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    buf := bufPool.Get()
    defer bufPool.Put(buf)
    err := template.ExecuteTemplate(buf, "forms/create.html", user)
    // or err := json.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(value)
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }

    buf.WriteTo(w)
}
```

This uses the [bpool](https://github.com/oxtoacart/bpool) library.